# internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'F:\mernbootcamp\harrycodname

Tags: node.js, node-modules

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'F:\mernbootcamp\harrycode\D1'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Comment: please write, what is your problem and tell, what you were trying to do. If you just pase your Error Message, it's difficult to answer.

Comment: A bit vague to understand what are you trying to do and please submit some code with the request